# Resources$NotFoundException - Failed to open file '...fragment_list.xml': No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I am learning MVVM and have run into an issue, and I am getting the following errors:

```
Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/fragment_list.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f0b002f
```

and

```
Failed to open file '/data/data/software.genau.dogs/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/res/layout/fragment_list.xml': No such file or directory
```

I know the file exists in my layout, and there are no errors or warnings listed for the fragment_list.xml file. In the design view, everything is laid out the way I want and it looks correct.

To try and correct the issue I've tried some of the basic things like clean project and rebuilding, and restarted the program (and my machine). Also, I've tried different ways to override fun onCreateView() with and without binding.

I would appreciate some help.

Here is the MVVM layout:
[pic from Android studio folder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkUzs.png)

Here is my code for ListFragment.kt:

```
package software.genau.dogs.view

    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
    import androidx.navigation.Navigation
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import software.genau.dogs.R
    import software.genau.dogs.databinding.FragmentListBinding
    import software.genau.dogs.viewmodel.ListViewModel
    
    class ListFragment : Fragment() {
        private lateinit var binding: FragmentListBinding
        private lateinit var viewModel: ListViewModel
        private val dogsListAdapter = DogsListAdapter(arrayListOf())
    
    
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
        }
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListViewModel::class.java)
            viewModel.refresh()
    
            binding.dogsList.apply {
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                adapter = dogsListAdapter
            }
            observeViewModel()
        }
    
        fun observeViewModel() {
            viewModel.dogs.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { dogs ->
                dogs?.let {
                    binding.dogsList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    dogsListAdapter.updateDogList(dogs)
                }
            })
    
            viewModel.dogsLoadError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { isError ->
                isError?.let {
                    binding.listError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            })
    
            viewModel.loading.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { isLoading ->
                isLoading?.let {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = if (it) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
                    if (it) {
                        binding.listError.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        binding.dogsList.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    
    }
```

Here is the code for fragment_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/dogsList"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listError"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/list_fragment_error_msg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dogsList"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dogsList" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dogsList"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dogsList" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is MainActivity.kt:

```
package software.genau.dogs.view

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.NavAction
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import software.genau.dogs.R
import software.genau.dogs.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, null)
    }
}
```

Here is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.MainActivity">


        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/dog_navigation"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Here are the errors from logcat:

```
2021-11-17 12:29:08.420 12809-12809/software.genau.dogs E/ware.genau.dog: Failed to open file '/data/data/software.genau.dogs/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/res/layout/fragment_list.xml': No such file or directory
2021-11-17 12:29:08.420 12809-12809/software.genau.dogs D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-11-17 12:29:08.425 12809-12809/software.genau.dogs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: software.genau.dogs, PID: 12809
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/fragment_list.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f0b002f
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:1264)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2426)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2402)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1252)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:530)
        at software.genau.dogs.view.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.kt:35)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/layout/fragment_list.xml
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenXmlAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:1092)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:1248)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2426) 
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2402) 
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1252) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:530) 
        at software.genau.dogs.view.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.kt:35) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this issue by making a small change in the XML (code editor) e.g changing or adding a margin to any View in the layout file.
Then I went to top menu Build -> Clean Project followed by Build -> Rebuild Project.
I think what happened is Android Studio/Gradle lost track of the changes made to the file, so it is not included when recompiling as it thinks it is there unmodified. By making a small arbitrary change to the file Gradle sees it has been modified so includes the layout as expected.

Comment: Pretty amazing how nuking all caches didn't work but this did the trick.

Comment: this works, properly

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I solved my issue.

I renamed the `fragment_list.xml` to `fragment_list2.xml`
then added a new `fragment_list.xml`. Finally, I copied all the data from the original file to the new file.

The new `fragment_list.xml` is now recognized and the program is running.